# How to display proper output when using re.findall() in python?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I made a python script to get the latest stock price from the Yahoo Finance.

```
import urllib.request
import re

htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GOOG");

htmltext = htmlfile.read();

price = re.findall(b'<span id="yfs_l84_goog">(.+?)</span>',htmltext);
print(price);
```

It works smoothly but when I output the price it comes out like this
`[b'1,217.04']`

This might be a petty issue to ask but I'm new to python scripting so please help me if you can. 

I want to get rid of 'b'. If I remove 'b' from `b'<span id="yfs_l84_goog">"`then it shows this error.

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 201, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I want the output to be just

```
1,217.04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b''` is a syntax for [`bytes`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview) literals in Python. It is how you could define byte sequences in Python source code.

What you see in the output is the representation of the single `bytes` object inside the `price` list returned by `re.findall()`. You could decode it into a string and print it:

```
>>> for item in price:
...     print(item.decode()) # assume utf-8
... 
1,217.04
```

You could also write bytes directly to stdout e.g., `sys.stdout.buffer.write(price[0])`.

You could [use an html parser instead of a regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgi
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GOOG'

def is_price_tag(tag, attrs):
    return tag == 'span' and dict(attrs).get('id') == 'yfs_l84_goog'

class Parser(HTMLParser):
    """Extract tag's text content from html."""
    def __init__(self, html, starttag_callback):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.contents = []
        self.intag = None
        self.starttag_callback = starttag_callback
        self.feed(html)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.intag = self.starttag_callback(tag, attrs)
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.intag = False
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.intag:
            self.contents.append(data)

# download and convert to Unicode
response = urlopen(url)
_, params = cgi.parse_header(response.headers.get('Content-Type', ''))
html = response.read().decode(params['charset'])

# parse html (extract text from the price tag)
content = Parser(html, is_price_tag).contents[0]
print(content)
```

Check whether yahoo provides API that doesn't require web scraping.

Comment: It worked great using item.decode(), does it convert bytes to string?

Comment: @SaurabhRana: yes. `some_bytes.decode(character_encoding) == some_unicode_text`

Answer (score 0):

Okay after searching for a while. I found the solution.Works fine for me.

```
import urllib.request 
import re

htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GOOG");

htmltext = htmlfile.read();

pattern = re.compile('<span id="yfs_l84_goog">(.+?)</span>');

price = pattern.findall(str(htmltext));
print(price);
```

Comment: don't call `str(some_bytes_object_that_might_be_text)` unconditionally. If the page is not encoded in `sys.getdefaultencoding()` then `str()` may produce a wrong result (sometimes silently). You could [use `Content-Type` header to get character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22020377/4279)